# How to remove the credentials that are used by http digest authentication in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

I try to called `[ASIHTTPRequest clearSession]`, but the request can still return 200 status, even if use the wrong username and password.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

**ASIHTTPRequest** objects store the user information in a "session" by default, you have to **disable** this feature on every request you create to get the behavior that you want.

From the website docs:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
[request setUseSessionPersistence:NO]; //this is the line that disables storage
```

More on it [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#storing_credentials_in_the_session).

Comment: It is not enough, Also must be disabled cookie store for the Request. [request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];